# How to make form resulting in '/:category_id/:id' where :category_id and :id should be entered in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have implemented search via correspondent urls (routes): `/:category_id/:id` (I just expect not ids but "names" in my controller actions code)

E.g. 
`/category_name/search_pattern_for_item_name`
will look for items with names similar to "search_pattern_for_item_name" within catagory with the "category_name" name.

Now I want to make a form and bind it with this route, i.e. on submit I want to be redirected to the route mentioned above...

I know how to write only this:

```
<%= form_tag({ :controller => "items", :action => "show" }, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :id %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :category_id, @category.name  %>
  <%= submit_tag "Filter" %>
<% end %>
```

But this results in the `No route matches {:controller=>"items"}` error unless I put this into the view correspondent to the ItemsController#show action. And even in the latter (succeeded) case I will get the url on submit (when searching for "it") not what I expect: `http://localhost:3000/category1/item12?utf8=%E2%9C%93&id=it&category_id=category1&commit=Filter`

Though I expected `http://localhost:3000/category1/it`

**How to implement correct form for my case or what did I wrong?**

my routes.rb:

```
  resources :categories, path: '', only: [:index] do
    resources :items, path: '', only: [:index, :show]
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_tag({ :controller => "items", :action => "show", 
        :id =>params[:id], :category_id =>params[:category_id] }, 
        :method => "get") do %>
```

Comment: It uses values for :id and :category_id from params hash at the moment of rendering view, but I need this values being taken from the form on  submit... 
Seems like it's impossible to make such form only with rails... maybe I need to some javascripting... What do you think?

Comment: add match `'/items/show' => "items#show"` in your `routes.rb`